# C# XNA Exception: “Cannot Open File”

Tags: c#, exception, xna

I'm at a complete loss for why it's not working. All it does is give me the cannot open file exception on both images. Any advice?

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        pixelTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("\\Images\\pixel");
        treeTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("\\images\\tree");

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a folder at the root of your content project called Images? Are the pixel and tree images in that folder?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing absolute file paths.

Your paths should resemble this instead (note the extension and lack of slash at the start):

```
pixelTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\pixel.png");
treeTexture  = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\tree.png");
```

In general, to troubleshoot asset loading problems, you need to double check:

- That the asset is indeed part of the content project
- That the properties (build type, etc.) on the asset are set properly (select in solution explorer then press F4 to open the properties)
- That the path in your string matches the path on disk relative to the content root directory, and includes the file extension
- That the content root directory (`Content.RootDirectory`) is set to the right value

Comment: Now it's giving me a file not found exception. Maybe I have them loaded wrong? All I did was right click content pipeline, add existing file, etc.

Comment: @kingluke: Are you sure the relative path and file extensions (I only guessed PNG) are correct? And is it "images" or "Images" (with a capital I)? (I can't remember whether XNA is case-sensitive but it doesn't hurt to get it right.)

Comment: +1 But I don't agree with calling the absolute paths the OP passed in as malformed. They're perfectly valid absolute paths; they should just be relative instead. Also, file extensions are optional when loading content and are only necessary to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: Dum me. The pictures aren't even in an a file called image. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: @itsme86: You're right, I was reminded of UNC paths (which must start with 2 backslashes), but of course absolute paths relative to the current drive are formatted like the original strings. Thanks for calling me out on the file extension resolution too, I could have sworn they were required (perhaps in an older version?) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that you're passing an absolute path instead of a relative path. You just need to drop the 2 backslashes at the beginning of your path strings.